# How to store parameters from log to somewhere for later use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get parameters (in this case customers' shipping info) from log to somewhere for later use? What's the best approach?

Comment: Are they already written out to a log file, then?

Comment: Yes, they indeed are.

Comment: Do you know *how* these values are being written out to the log file?

Comment: Do you mean this?
`"stripeEmail"=>"example@email.com", "stripeBillingName"=>"Example BillingName", "stripeBillingAddressLine1"=>"Example BillingAddress", "stripeBillingAddressZip"=>"12345", "stripeBillingAddressCity"=>"ExampleCity", "stripeBillingAddressCountry"=>"ExampleCountry", "stripeBillingAddressCountryCode"=>"EX", "stripeShippingName"=>"Example ShippingName", "stripeShippingAddressLine1"=>"Example ShippingAddress", "stripeShippingAddressZip"=>"12345", "stripeShippingAddressCity"=>"ExampleCityy", "stripeShippingAddressCountry"=>"ExampleCountry", "stripeShippingAddressCountryCode"=>"EX"`

Comment: No, not that specifically.  Although if that's the kind of thing you're interested in capturing, what's the hangup?  Do you know if that is explicitly or implicitly written to a log somewhere?

Comment: I want to capture all those params, yes. I don't quite get what you're after.

Comment: Privacy concerns aside, my question is, do you understand where those parameters are coming from?  That's where you have to begin with the logging bit, since unless you know where those values enter your system at, you won't be able *to* log them.

Comment: Surely. They're coming from a Stripe checkout form, which is processed by charges controller.

Comment: In a Rails app the "somewhere for later use" usually means in the database. If there is a controller action or other method somewhere that is receiving those parameters and writing them to a file, then it should be easy to get that same method to also write them to the database. I think this is probably what @Makoto is leading up to. But if you really want to read them back in from the file you'll have to tell us what format they are in in the file